# как с помощью java script редактировать стили

Tags: javascript, css

Есть ли способ перезаписать текущие стили по средством js ?

Я подключил скрипт со стилями и он подрублен через cdn, как можно его перебить?

Comment: можно и своим css перебить легко....просто свои стили должны подключиться позже чем cdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [jQuery.css](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.square').css(
    {
      background: 'yellow',
      border: 'solid 3px green'
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.square{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```